# NetworkStream Sleep() issue

Tags: c#, async-await, tcpclient, asyncsocket, networkstream

I have written a TCP Server, in which number of bytes to read is prefixed in two-bytes header. After reading from the stream and sending the response back to the client, both NetworkStream and TcpClient are disposed. The problem is that the client doesn't seem to receive my response unless I uncomment Thread.Sleep() line. Here is the code:

```
using (var tcpClient = await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
{
    tcpClient.NoDelay = true;

    using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    {
        var twoBytesHeader = new TwoByteHeader();
        var headerBuffer = new byte[twoBytesHeader.HeaderLength];

        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII, true))
        {
            headerBuffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(twoBytesHeader.HeaderLength);

            int newOffset;
            var msgLength = twoBytesHeader.GetMessageLength(headerBuffer, 0, out newOffset);

            var buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(msgLength);

            string msgASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

            var bufferToSend = await ProcessMessage(msgASCII);

            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII, true))
            {
                binaryWriter.Write(bufferToSend);
                binaryWriter.Flush();
            }

            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When Sleep is uncommented, the client receives response and then indicates that client has disconected. I can't figure out the reason of this behaviour

Comment: if you need to be sure there was no error in sending your data, then async may not be the answer surely, you want to send it, know it sent, and then close?

Comment: Thank you for the response. In this case I am await-ing WriteAsync, so it will wait until all bytes are sent and only then close the connection. There must be something else I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that a read will read as many bytes as you specified. Instead, it will read at least one byte. Your code needs to be able to deal with that. `BinaryReader.ReadBytes` will allow you to read an exact number of bytes and get rid of some of your boilerplate code.

Also, you probably should not use ASCII encoding which is the worst possible encoding.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the possible problem with reading using stream, I will take that into account. As for encoding, I have no choice as the client sends ASCII encoded messages. Anyway, I still cannot figure out, why putting Sleep() after stream.Flush() makes the client to receive response. I've read about Nagle's algorithm, but I assume Flush acts similarly as if I have set NoDelay property

Comment: Maybe the client is broken? Post the code.; The issue that I described might cause the server to crash and not send a rely. So you probably should fix that anyway and post the new code.; Flush on a NetworkStream does nothing. It can't change anything.

Comment: The problem is that the client is an external application which I don't have access to. simple client I wrote for testing works just fine. I will make changes you suggested and see if it helps, thanks

Comment: I've updated the initial code and gave it a try, but result is the same. Sleep-ing makes the trick and I can't understand the reason

Comment: Maybe the client is broken. Disable Nagling to try to work around the broken client. As explained Flush does nothing. I never found a way to flush a socket

Comment: I have disabled Nagling: tcpClient.NoDelay = true; I've ran out of ideas

Comment: How do you know whether the client received the response or not? Maybe we need to questions such assumptions... Otherwise I'm out of ideas. A final experiment would be to add `socket.Shutdown(Both); socket.Disconnect();` in the place of the sleep line. What happens then?

Comment: I have access to the client's logs but not the source codes.. I also noticed that if I put Sleep between stream's using closing bracket and tcpClient's using closing bracket, the client's log reflects that the server cannot even read the message.. So I assume it must be something with the stream.. Or maybe there's something wrong with the way I use asynchrony? Thank you so much for trying to help me, I will try the case with shutdown..

Comment: After making a detailed logging and analyzing network traffic, I found out that there is only one instance of client which sends both network and operation messages through the same socket. So closing the connection after operation response, ruins everything.. Thank you for spending your time helping, I learnt a lot during the investigation.. Won't take for granted any "facts" anymore unless I see it myself :)